# Fastest way to migrate from sql server to sqlite for large datasets

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sqlite, data-migration

I have a database with more than 32 million records, I have to migrate it from SQL Server to Sqlite.

I have tried SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) with the help of this article
http://dbauman.blogspot.com/2009/03/connecting-to-sqlite-through-ssis.html

but the process is very very slow, how can I migrate this data?

Comment: How much time does it take for you to dump the data into Sqlite using SSIS ? By enhancing the performance of DFT ,you can some how increase the speed

Comment: In the article ODBC is used, which usually is a poor choice if you have performance in mind; it just adds another abstraction layer. I found SQLite to be quite fast (I don't have any statistics at hand) when executing loads of prepared INSERT commands within a transaction, I never worked with SSIS unfortunately.

Comment: 10000 records takes mote than 30 minutes

Comment: Just give a try :-If you have indexes in your sqlite table then try to drop them and load the data and then rebuilt it again

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a C# utility to automatically do conversion from a SQL Server DB to a SQLite DB by 
liron.

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB) is the code project article.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use transactions in SQLite, else the Indices are built with every new record added, not when one block of work is done.

As i don't know about the structure of your data, it is hard to give concrete advice, but writing a small application that can read from SQLServer and write to SQLite is often a practical start for migration. With the bonus of having a full wrapper after migration, which you can use in future.

Comment: As @Damith mentioned the solution in this article: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26932/Convert-SQL-Server-DB-to-SQLite-DB